# IOS: disable gesture in a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

In my app I have this situation:
I have my main viewcontroller where I alloc a "flipwiecontroller" and add its view in this way

```
self.flipViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake (...);
[self.view addSubview:self.flipViewController.view];
```

and at this flipViewController I add some gesture (as pangesture, swipegesture and tapgesture for some control that I use on it)

when I press a button in this view I alloc another viewcontroller "paintingviewcontroller" in this way

```
[self.view addSubview:paintingViewController.view];
```

in this second view controller I have some buttons and another function, but when I try to do a swipegesture or a tapgesture it recognize the events of my "flipviewcontroller"

I don't understand, if I add a view controller over another viewcontroller, why gesture of flipviewcontroller are active yet?

thnaks

Comment: How did you add the gesture recognizers? They should be added to the view, not the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are disabling userIntercation on the paintingViewController, then, it's events are sent to his superview.
Also you can use `[UIView removeGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer]` to remove gestures.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the gesture recognizers? They should be added to the view, not the window. Perhaps that's the issue.

In case you have something like this:

```
[self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

You should change it to this:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```